# Extracting source code (HTML, CSS) from Wix sites

Tags: html, css, velo

I've spent 3 hours perfecting a site on Wix. I need to get the HTML and CSS so that I can publish it on my own hosting service. Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding regarding the tag `wix`. It is used for this software: http://wixtoolset.org/, not the website designer http://wix.com

Comment: https://www.wix.com/support/html5/domains/connecting-domains-purchased-elsewhere/kb/exporting-your-wix-site-elsewhere

Answer (score 5):

Wix website has clear instructions about viewing the source code but you won't get css element...see [this link](https://support.wix.com/en/article/viewing-your-page-source-code).

Answer (score 2):

You would have to parse your page, some frames will not get parsed though, but adding pics and videos and such you can do after, just learn how to add it to your html. I can post the code, but that has to be adjusted for your needs.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = self.driver
html_source = driver.page_source     
with codecs.open(path+'/scratch.html', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f: 
    f.write(html_source)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use WinHTTrack to download the offline website